# Bash get MD5 of online file

Tags: command-line, bash, md5sum

I need to get the MD5 hash of an online file, and then compare it to a file on the local machine.

How can I do this in bash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `curl` to fetch the online file:

```sh
curl -sL http://www.your.fi/le | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

To compare against another one, store it in a variable and then proceed:

```sh
online_md5="$(curl -sL http://www.your.fi/le | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
local_md5="$(md5sum "$file" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"

if [ "$online_md5" = "$local_md5" ]; then
    echo "hurray, they are equal!"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`wget` can download to standard output with `-O-`.

```
 wget http://example.com/some-file.html -O- \
     | md5sum \
     | cut -f1 -d' ' \
     | diff - <(md5sum local-file.html | cut -f1 -d' ')
```

`md5sum` appends the file name after the MD5, you can remove it with `cut`.

Comment: Could you please explain what the `diff - <(md5sum local-file.html | cut -f1 -d' ')` does?

Comment: @FinlayRoelofs: it runs `diff` on the pipe output and output of the command in `<(...)` process substitution, i.e. it compares the MD5 sums of the downloaded file and the local file as requested.

Answer (score 1):

```
 wget -q -O- http://example.com/your_file | md5sum | sed 's:-$:local_file:' | md5sum -c
```

Replace `http://example.com/your_file` with the URL of your online file and `local_file` with the name of your local file

Comment: Could you please explain what the `sed` does?

Comment: The output of `md5sum` is a line containing the checksum and the file name. `md5sum -c` checks that file name for the checksum.  the `sed` command replaces the `-` that `md5sum` uses for `stdin` with the name of the local file so the `md5sum -c` at the end verifies that the local file's checksum is the one of the online file.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do it directly. Use `wget` or `curl` to print the remote file's contents and also print the contents of the local file. Pass both to `md5sum` and compare the output:

```
$ md5sum <(wget  http://www.exacmple.com/file -O- 2>/dev/null) <(cat localfile) 
733f328d8cff7dd89970ec34a70aa14f  /dev/fd/63
733f328d8cff7dd89970ec34a70aa14f  /dev/fd/62
```

The first line will be the remote file's `md5sum` and the second is the local's.

Comment: are these expected to be the same? for example running: `md5sum <(wget http://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml -O- 2>/dev/null) <(cat P:/stack.xml)` gives me two different checksums...is there a certain way to download the file?

Comment: @R.M. what file? If you get different checksums then the files are different. What is `P:/stack.xml`? Does it maybe have a final newline? Did you save it in a text editor? That would have added a newline.

Comment: i downloaded it using `download.file(..., mode = 'wb')` in R.

Comment: @R.M. then it almost certainly added a newline (`\n` or, if on Windows as your path suggests, `\r\n`) to the end of the file. So the content isn't exactly the same because of that final newline.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me linking to my question, but I don't think the `\r\n` was the issue--I tried truncating the file by 1 and 2 bytes and still got different checksums than what `wget` returns. Here's the example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602271/compare-md5sum-of-a-file-online-versus-and-that-file-locally-downloaded/

Comment: @R.M. either way, if the checksums are different, the data are different. So you will need to figure out why you are getting different data.

Answer (score 0):

Via `wget` and `md5sum` and `awk` as a long one-liner **=)**

```
awk 'FNR == NR {a[0]=$1; next} {if (a[0]==$1) {print "match"; exit} {print "no match"}}'\
 <(wget -O- -q URL | md5sum)\
 <(md5sum local_file)
```

---

Example

```
$ awk 'FNR == NR {a[0]=$1; next} {if (a[0]==$1) {print "match"; exit} {print "no match"}}' <(wget -O- -q http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/hunspell/libhunspell-1.2-0_1.2.8-6ubuntu1_i386.deb | md5sum) <(md5sum libhunspell-1.2-0_1.2.8-6ubuntu1_i386.deb)
match

$ awk 'FNR == NR {a[0]=$1; next} {if (a[0]==$1) {print "match"; exit} {print "no match"}}' <(wget -O- -q http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/hunspell/libhunspell-1.2-0_1.2.8-6ubuntu1_i386.deb | md5sum) <(md5sum foo) 
no match
```